# Difference between regular expressions: $(0^*1^*)^*$ and $(0+1)^*$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the following regular expressions: $(0^*1^*)^*$ and $(0+1)^*$ ? To me they look like generating the same string.

Comment: They do generate the same strings. The real question is how to prove it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The language of both regular expressions is the same, $L((0+1)^*)=L((0^*1^*)^*)$. This follows from the following three claims:

#### Claim 1:

> if $L_1 \subseteq L_2$, then $L_1^* \subseteq L_2^*$.

#### Claim 2:

> $L(0+1) \subseteq L(0^*1^*)$

#### Claim 3:

> $ (0^*1^*)^* \subseteq (0+1)^* \equiv \Sigma^*$

The 2nd and 3rd claims are trivial. Prove the first claim and you're done.

Note however, that the two regular expressions are not *the same* (ie., they are different!). They are **equivalent** in the sense of the language they generate. They are different in *the way* they generate it.

Comment: The string "1" is in the second language. Is it in the first? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the "+" notation.

Comment: @Joe the `+` sign is OR, sometimes it is written as `|` (like in: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory)). So $0+1$ means $0$ or $1$, and the string `1` is in the language.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, since "+" can also mean "1 or more" in many implementations of regular expressions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts

Comment: @joe right, there is a kleene-plus, defined as $0^+ \equiv 00^*$. While the kleene-plus is a unary operator, the "or" sign is a binary operator. I agree this can be confusing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write it $(\{0\} \cup \{1\})^*$?

Comment: @phant0m  $\{0\}$ is a language. $0$ is a regular expression (which generates the language $\{0\}$). In the same manner, $(0+1)^*$ is the regular expression that generates the language $\{0,1\}^* = (\{0\}\cup\{1\})^*$.

Answer (score -3):

They are not the same. When we say $0+1$ it signifies a union operation, which is "either or". So either $0$ or $1$ can be present and the ${}^*$ indicates that it can be present any number of times.

On the other hand, $01$ is a concatenation of the symbols $0$ and $1$.
So $(0^*1^*)$ means $0$ can occur any number of times followed by $1$ occurring any number of times and the outer asterisk denotes that such a sequence can occur in the string $n$ times.

Comment: I'm not sure what your answer adds. It's already been established that the two regular expressions, while textually different, describe the same language (*viz.* $\{0,1\}^*$). Your answer doesn't even make clear that they do describe the same language: in fact, I can't even tell if you're trying to say, incorrectly, that the regular expressions match different languages.  $X^*$ doesn't mean that a specific sequence matching $X$ "occurs in the string $n$ times": it means that the string can be broken into an arbitrary number of blocks, which may be different but each must match $X$.